# How to send Emails from React JS(from Front End) without help of backend?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make one feature website that allow to connect user's email account to particular Login and allow to send emails from front End directly. I am using React Js as front end.

Comment: Please try to ask a about a specific problem, people here cannot write you entire project for you. Have a look at this to understand how to write better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FormSpree](https://formspree.io/). You just have to provide the url in form action.

Comment: I guess it also uses a backend. But yes, you don't need to implement your own backend